# The clang compiler does not support a feature it reportedly supports

Tags: clang, compiler-optimization, apple-m1, arm64

I'm trying to tailor compiler flags of clang-11 to the `apple-m1` CPU, which clang-11 doesn't know about yet.

The output of `/usr/bin/clang -E - -mcpu=apple-m1 -###` on macOS outputs a command with flags like these in it:  `"-target-feature" "+zcz"`

From that you can infer the following features of the CPU:

```
armv8.5a+fp-armv8+neon+crc+crypto+dotprod+fp16fml+ras+lse+rdm+rcpc+zcm+zcz+fullfp16+sm4+sha3+sha2+aes
```

However, out of these, `+fp-armv8+neon+zcm+zcz+fullfp16` are not recognised to be valid by any clang compiler:

```
$ cc -march=armv8.5a+zcz test.c 
clang-11: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=armv8.5a+zcz'
```

How can I tell clang to optimise for those target flags?

Comment: If your clang supports `-mcpu=apple-m1`, why not just use that?  Or are you running a different version of clang on a different system?  It shouldn't be surprising if a different clang doesn't know about some CPU features that apple-clang knows about.  Use a newer clang (e.g. https://godbolt.org/ has nightly builds of clang 15 trunk for armv8), or omit the CPU-feature options your clang doesn't know about.

Comment: `clang-11` predates the release of Apple M1 by about a month. Apart from that, if you're using Xcode on macOS then you have `AppleClang`, which lags behind upstream clang by roughly a year, but commonly ships Apple-specific features that won't make it into upstream for another 2 years.

Comment: I am aware newer versions of LLVM/clang exist, thank you. This needs to work with clang-11 specifically.

Comment: Short of you backporting features from Clang 13.1.6 to Clang 11, there is no way to answer this question.

Comment: As stated, there isn't *any* clang compiler which recognises these flags. `clang-13: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=armv8.5a+zcz'`

Comment: I'm aware. I mentioned backporting. But I was not clear. Is your question seeking an answer of how to take features from future clang and backport to 11? Or is this an XY problem. Why do you need it to work on 11? That is the part I can't understand yet.

Comment: Please read closely. Not even clang-*13* (or *any* other version for that matter) recognises these features when set manually but *somehow* enables them when using `-mcpu=apple-m1`.

Comment: Well, M1 is an arm8.5-a cpu. So that makes sense. I just fetched clan 15, it accepts "-march=armv8-a" but not "armv8.5a" (notice -a). Apple's clan 13/14 both accept "-march=armv8-a". None support +zcz.

Comment: As per the OP, apparently they do support zcz and all the other target features but don't accept the manual declaration.